# Can't start SFML app on Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, sfml

Installed SFML on Mac OS according to tutorial http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/start-osx.php (Xcode 6.1), it's kinda worked, so I can create SMFL app, but when i try to build that standart project it comes with the following error

```
Ld /Users/andreybondar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test-draycgeyywzpqjgugruuudxcdqqj/Build/Intermediates/Test.build/Debug/Test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Test normal x86_64
    cd /Users/andreybondar/Desktop/Test
    export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.10
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk -L/Users/andreybondar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test-draycgeyywzpqjgugruuudxcdqqj/Build/Products/Debug -L/usr/local/lib -F/Users/andreybondar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test-draycgeyywzpqjgugruuudxcdqqj/Build/Products/Debug -F/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/andreybondar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test-draycgeyywzpqjgugruuudxcdqqj/Build/Intermediates/Test.build/Debug/Test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Test.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.10 -frameworksfml-system -frameworksfml-window -frameworksfml-graphics -frameworksfml-audio -frameworksfml-network -stdlib=libc++ -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/andreybondar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test-draycgeyywzpqjgugruuudxcdqqj/Build/Intermediates/Test.build/Debug/Test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Test_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/andreybondar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test-draycgeyywzpqjgugruuudxcdqqj/Build/Intermediates/Test.build/Debug/Test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Test

clang: error: unknown argument: '-frameworksfml-system'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-frameworksfml-window'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-frameworksfml-graphics'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-frameworksfml-audio'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-frameworksfml-network'
```

So, what I should do to make it work, cause i already tried to manually put all SFML files in their directories, and don't know what else I can do.

Comment: Well those options should be `-framework sfml-system`, etc.  It looks like that template is broken.  You can probably fix it within the Xcode project settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading the old version of the tutorial. Read the ones for [SFML **2.1**](http://sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/) instead. One of the differences is this message:

> If you have Xcode 5, you must use the new version of the templates.

which is available on the download page. Long story short, this update of the template fixes a regression introduced in Xcode 5 and later.

[source](http://sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/start-osx.php#introduction)